# How to asynchronously distribute product-yielding from a dataframe in scrapy spider

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, asynchronous, scrapy

### Is there a way to utilize Scrapy's asynchronous architecture when yielding products from a dataframe?

---

#### Overview

I have a spider in one of my Scrapy projects that differs from your typical logic of a spider as follows:

1. Crawls an online file directory to get the most recent versions of two zip files that both contain multiple csv files
2. Extracts the csv files to the current working directory
3. Utilizes `pandas.read_csv` to read each csv into its own dataframe
4. Performs `pandas.merge` operations to combine the data into a two final dataframes (one is the main dataframe and the other is a supporting dataframe where there's a one-to-many (main-to-supporting) row relationship
5. Finally, the spider loops through the main dataframe, starts populating a scrapy item, then gathers the additional data from the supporting dataframe, and yields a complete item

The logic works, but the process takes about 5 1/2 hours to complete since it's dealing with 500k items and essentially becomes synchronous once it starts yielding items from the dataframes.

Below is the code I'm using to accomplish all of this. The bottleneck happens in the `process_csvs` function.

```py
from ..items.redacted import Loader, REDACTEDItem
from scrapy.exceptions import CloseSpider
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import zipfile
import scrapy
import json
import os


class REDACTEDSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'REDACTED'
    allowed_domains = ['REDACTED']
    start_urls = ['https://REDACTED/datasets/']
    # custom_settings = dict(TESTING_MODE=True, LOG_LEVEL='DEBUG')
    zip_filename = 'temp_redacted_data.zip'

    def parse(self, response):
        main_file_date = supporting_file_date = datetime.min
        main_file = supporting_file = None
        for link in response.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "primary_csv")]/@href').getall():
            link_date = datetime.strptime(link.rstrip('.zip')[-10:], '%Y-%m-%d')
            if link_date > main_file_date:
                main_file = link
                main_file_date = link_date
        if not main_file:
            raise CloseSpider('primary_csv zip file not found')
        self.logger.info('Found latest primary_csv file link (%s)' % main_file)
        main_file = f"https://REDACTED/datasets/{main_file}"
        for link in response.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "supporting_csv")]/@href').getall():
            link_date = datetime.strptime(link.rstrip('.zip')[-10:], '%Y-%m-%d')
            if link_date > supporting_file_date:
                supporting_file = link
                supporting_file_date = link_date
        if not supporting_file:
            raise CloseSpider('supporting_csv zip file not found')
        self.logger.info('Found latest supporting_csv file link (%s)' % supporting_file)
        supporting_file = f"https://REDACTED/datasets/{supporting_file}"

        # we pass supporting_file to essentially download the files sequentially
        # and so that we can make sure the files are downloaded before moving on to ingesting them
        self.logger.info('Downloading primary_csv zip file')
        yield scrapy.Request(main_file, callback=self.handle_zip, cb_kwargs=dict(supporting_file=supporting_file))

    def handle_zip(self, response, supporting_file=None):
        file_alias = 'primary_csv' if supporting_file else 'supporting_csv'
        # download zip - if this is the second time this function is called it will overwrite the first zip file
        # since we've already extracted the files we need from it
        self.logger.info(f"Saving {file_alias} zip file")
        with open(self.zip_filename, 'wb') as usda_file:
            usda_file.write(response.body)
        # extract zip contents
        self.logger.info(f"Extracting files from {file_alias} zip file")
        with zipfile.ZipFile(self.zip_filename, 'r') as zfile:
            if supporting_file:
                # we're extracting the first file, and still need to queue up the supporting_file
                zfile.extract('primary_csv_file_1.csv')
                zfile.extract('primary_csv_file_2.csv')
                zfile.extract('primary_csv_file_3.csv')
            else:
                # we're extracting the supporting_file now
                zfile.extract('supporting_csv_file.csv')

        if supporting_file:
            self.logger.info('Downloading supporting_csv zip file')
            yield scrapy.Request(supporting_file, callback=self.handle_zip)
        else:
            # remove the zipfile since we no longer need it
            # this will free up some storage space in case we need extra for the staging db
            os.remove(self.zip_filename)
            # both files have been unzipped, so we can move onto processing the csvs
            self.logger.info('Processing CSV files')
            
            # FIXME: This essentially bottlenecks into yielding items from a single thread
            yield from self.process_csvs()
    
    def process_csvs(self):
        primary_csv_file_1 = pd.read_csv('primary_csv_file_1.csv', usecols=[...], dtype=dict(...))
        primary_csv_file_2 = pd.read_csv('primary_csv_file_2.csv', usecols=[...], dtype=dict(...))
        primary_csv_file_3 = pd.read_csv('primary_csv_file_3.csv', usecols=[...], dtype=dict(...))
        supporting_csv_file = pd.read_csv('supporting_csv_file.csv', usecols=[...], dtype=dict(...))

        # Join the above four files into two pandas dataframes
        # Step 1: Join primary_csv_file_2.csv into primary_csv_file_1.csv
        primary_csv_file_1 = pd.merge(primary_csv_file_1, primary_csv_file_2, on='id', how='left')
        primary_csv_file_1.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True, inplace=True)
        # primary_csv_file_1 should now have most of the essential columns needed to create a full item
        # Step 2: Join supporting_csv_file.csv into primary_csv_file_3.csv
        primary_csv_file_3 = pd.merge(primary_csv_file_3, supporting_csv_file, left_on='supporting_id', right_on='id', how='left')
        primary_csv_file_3.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True, inplace=True)
        # primary_csv_file_3 should now have an additional column from supporting_csv_file

        # TODO: This is where I would like to fork the function in order to take full advantage of Scrapy's asynchronous processing
        for product in primary_csv_file_1.itertuples():
            loader = Loader(item=REDACTEDItem())
            loader.add_value('url', 'REDACTED')
            loader.add_value('category', product.category)
            loader.add_value('upc', product.upc)
            loader.add_value('brand', product.brand)
            loader.add_value('product_name', product.name)

            # Filter primary_csv_file_3 by id to get all nutrients and nutrient values for this product
            p_nutrients = primary_csv_file_3[primary_csv_file_3.id == product.supporting_id]
            nutrients = []
            for nutrient in p_nutrients.itertuples():
                nutrients.append(dict(
                    alias=nutrient.name,
                    value=nutrient.amount,
                    unit_of_measure=nutrient.units
                ))
            loader.add_value('nutrition', json.dumps(nutrients))

            yield loader.load_item()

        # remove the csv files to free up space
        os.remove('primary_csv_file_1.csv')
        os.remove('primary_csv_file_2.csv')
        os.remove('primary_csv_file_3.csv')
        os.remove('supporting_csv_file.csv')
```

Comment: Since the task is CPU-bound, I think your only solution would be to see if you can use `multiprocessing` to handle some of the CPU-heavy parts.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Could you provide a working example of how I can do that while managing to still yield the items back to the initial process? I need all items to be yielded from the originating crawler so that they can pass through the pipelines. Due to data migration limitations I cannot treat each process as it's own crawler instance because that would lead to one instance of products overwriting the other instances (so I'd end up with a 1/4 items if using 4 processes instead of the full lot of items).

Comment: I’m not familiar myself with combining Scrapy (or Twisted, which Scrapy uses for concurrency) and multiprocessing. I know Twisted has `deferToThread`, but a separate thread will simply prevent CPU-intensive stuff from blocking network input/output, multiprocessing is the only thing that can allow you to use more than one processor (assuming your CPU has more than one, and you wish to utilize them).

Comment: Are `REDACTEDItems` just data read in from the csvs or is this class reaching out to the internet and downloading something?

Comment: As can be seen in the `parse` function, the spider downloads csv files from an online site

Comment: Maybe scrapy isn't the right tool.  Have you considered `dask` for this? https://examples.dask.org/delayed.html

Comment: @anon01 the first line of the bounty clearly states I'm looking for a Scrapy-related solution.

Comment: @CaffeinatedMike I understand that was the framing of the question - the point is that it may not be the right tool for the job

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to break it up into two separate .py?

The first does the crawling and copying - after copying it updates a redis db that contains a list of the appropriate file names - its running on twisted or whatever).

The second runs on an internal python scheduler or similar and accesses the redis db for the unworked files - and can then parse out the work using multiprocessing.

Trying to get twisted to play nicely with multiprocessing is likely to end badly - so if you can decouple them its likely to yield a quicker solution.

If you need to get info back to the first (twisted) .py, it can also poll the same redis db for updates from the second .py

---

Update #1

```
import redis
r = redis.Redis(db=0)
r.set("inputValName", inputVal)

extractedVal = r.get("inputValName").decode()
```

Comment: Setting up a redis db for a single spider seems like way too much additional overhead for a project that has over 30 spiders currently (and growing).

Comment: It might surprise you how light redis is in terms of syntax. [I've added the syntax to the original comment as its a mess in this!]

You can pack up JSONs as one inputVal to compact things up if you wanted.

In terms of memory overhead - if you only include paths to the files then the memory used would be minimal.

Comment: This doesn't align with what I need as a solution. I need something that can be used within a scrapy spider. Maybe what you're suggesting is possible to be used in that context, but your example does not show how that can be done.

Comment: True - I don't have time for a full blown solution - just suggesting a way out. This may help  a bit: https://scrapy-redis.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html#document-index